# Use a single wordpress category.php file for every category registered

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title suggests, I'm trying to use one category.php file for every category registered by a user in the back-end. I've always created category-[specific category].php files in the past but this feels very messy as the design usually remains the same.

Without being specific in the query I return all posts in all categories however, I want to be able to show the custom posts for only the category selected from the nav. The problem is, I can't seem to find a way to pass the category the user selected into the query in order to only return posts attributed to it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything specific to show a list of posts from a specific category. Take a look at this [article on the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates). Here is an excerpt from that page:

> In the case of categories, the hierarchy is fairly simple. For
>   instance, suppose the slug of the Category in question is news and the
>   Category ID is 6. The Template Hierarchy specifies that WordPress will
>   use the first Template file it finds in your current Theme's directory
>   from the following list:
>
> 1. category-slug.php
> 2. category-ID.php
> 3. category.php
> 4. archive.php
> 5. index.php

So all you need to do is create `category.php` in your theme and then view any category and it'll use that template. You can then use `is_category()` to check which category is currently being used if you want to do custom things depending on the category.

Comment: Thank you. I had looked at that page a few times and nothing was clicking. I've reused some of the example code from there and it looks to be working now.